# Change the color of AlertDialo Title

Tags: java, alert

I want to change the color of alert Dialog Title

```
enter code here

 String title="AlertDialog";

 builder.setTitle(  Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'> title</font>"));
```

So is there a way to pass the string title into the above method??

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: Okay, thanks! I've edited the tags of your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting the color in a variable:

```
String color = "#FF7F27";
builder.setTitle(  Html.fromHtml("<font color='" + color + "'>" + title + "</font>"));
```